# Local Javascript file stalling up my page. Why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Page not loading (http://playclassicsnake.com/Play) and it's very mysterious because after commenting/uncommenting blocks of server-side and client-side code I've determined that a local JavaScript file being included

```
@section ViewIncludesBottom
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/game.js"></script>
}
```

is stalling the page with a typical "This page unresponsive" error.

*Notes:*

- Happening both when I deploy to my local machine and when I deploy to the live server
- **I'm not aware of any updates I've made to this file recently**. That is the strange part. I've been working on other parts of my application and after a recent building of the project this page stopped working. **In fact, I just checked my source control and verified that I haven't modified this file for a long time, long before I noticed this issue a few days ago.**
- I can open the script just fine (http://playclassicsnake.com/Scripts/game.js)
- Same behavior in every browser I've tested it on.

Any guidance into how I can investigate the source of this error? **I'm almost 100% positive that it has nothing to do with the contents of the JS file.**

Comment: There is a tool called Dynatrace which you could try and see if you can locate what is stalling the site.

https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/AJAX/Dynatrace+AJAX+Edition+Community+Home

Comment: please disable bundling of your app, and test again